# Loads of errors when trying to use image cropper

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

[SOLVED] I had to change api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+' from build.gradle to 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'

I am trying to use this (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) image cropper in my project but is gives me loads of error messages and opens up one of the xml files that came with the cropper apparenty. Here are the error messages it gives me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gPfn2bbmoP-IrqRgyZEOF1olw66uproM/view?usp=sharing

I have no idea what to do since the xml is not written by me and I don't really know what can I change from the xml for keeping the croppper functional.

here is the xml code that android studio opens up when I try to build the app:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat"                                                                 parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
        <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
            <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
            <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
        </style>
        <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
            <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: you should open issue in the girhub repository to ask the developer of the library

Comment: have you declared the values? or are those already declared there?

Comment: What values do you mean?

Comment: please post your gradle.build(app) file

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you face **"AAPT2 error"** you must look for a solution by updating your gradle plugin version in build.gradle file :
what is your gradle plugin version?  change it like this :

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  }
 }
```